# Query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables t1 and t2 as following

**t1**

```
A    B    C    D   E
1    2    c    d    e
3    1    d    e    f
4    2    f    g    h
```

**t2**

```
A    B    
1    2    
8    6   
4    2
```

Here A,B,C,D,E are the columns of t1 and A,B are the columns of t2 where A and B are common columns.
 **What I have done so far**
I have written the following query

```
WITH temp as (
    select * 
    from t2
) 
select tab1.* 
from t1 tab1, temp tab2 
where (tab1.A!=tab2.A OR tab1.B!=tab2.B)
```

I **wanted** this output

```
A    B    C    D    E
3    1    d    e    f
```

But I am **getting** this output

```
A    B    C    D    E
1    2    c    d    e
1    2    c    d    e
3    1    d    e    f
3    1    d    e    f
3    1    d    e    f
4    2    f    g    h
4    2    f    g    h
```

What query should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like those rows from T1 that don't have corresponding rows in T2. The easiest way in my opinion is a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
psql=> select * from t1;
 a | b | c | d | e 
---+---+---+---+---
 1 | 2 | c | d | e
 3 | 1 | d | e | f
 4 | 2 | f | g | h
(3 rows)

psql=> select * from t2;
 a | b 
---+---
 1 | 2
 8 | 6
 4 | 2
(3 rows)

psql=> select t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.d, t1.e from t1 left outer join t2 on (t1.a = t2.a and t1.b = t2.b) where t2.a is null;
 a | b | c | d | e 
---+---+---+---+---
 3 | 1 | d | e | f
(1 row)
```

Edit: Here's the select without the where clause, with the rows from t2 added (otherwise it'd be just like a `select * from t1`). As you can see, the first row contains `NULL`s for `t2_a` and `t2_b`:

```
psql=> select t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t1.d, t1.e, t2.a as t2_a, t2.b as t2_b from t1 left outer join t2 on (t1.a = t2.a and t1.b = t2.b);
 a | b | c | d | e | t2_a | t2_b 
---+---+---+---+---+------+------
 3 | 1 | d | e | f |      |     
 1 | 2 | c | d | e |    1 |    2
 4 | 2 | f | g | h |    4 |    2
(3 rows)
```

Comment: It doesnt return any row :( Are u sure the query works fine? Can u tell how this query will be executed?

Comment: The paste above is from an actual psql session, so it definitely works for the test data you provided. The left outer join will add NULL instead of real data if the second table doesn't contain a matching row (based on the `ON (t1.a = t2.a and t1.b = t2.b)` condition).

Comment: Pardon me. It works actually. Can u please show the output after the left outer join without "t2.a is null" constraint? I am trying to understand the query.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE (a,b) NOT IN (SELECT a,b FROM t2);
```